# How to restart single app in uWSGI multiple apps environment?

Tags: python, uwsgi

I have some applications, which are written in python, those are managed under uWSGI on Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS.

Those apps are defined in /etc/uwsgi/apps-available/app001.xml, app002.xml, ..., and all apps xml files are symbolic linked from /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled directory.
When I have made some changes only one specific app, then I restart uwsgi processes.

```
sudo service uwsgi restart
```

But when I run above command to restart uWSGI processes, above command will restart all apps.

How can I restart only one single uwsgi instance?
I want to keep running another instance to avoid distractions related to process restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Emperor, just touch the config files, otherwise configure each instance to expose a pidfile (for using it with UNIX signals) or a master fifo (http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/MasterFIFO.html) or --touch-reload (http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#touch-reload)